# Storing Blob as int16 instead of int8 JS

Tags: javascript, web-audio-api

I'm actually storing data obtained via MediaRecorder from an audio stream into a Blob which, after being read by FileReader.readAsArrayBuffer(), is represented as a Int8Array. Is there any way to read it as an Int16Array instead?

The recording method has been extrated from [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Audio_API)

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

> After being read by `FileReader.readAsArrayBuffer()`, is represented as a `Int8Array`

No, it's a [buffer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/ArrayBuffer).

> Is there any way to read it as an Int16Array instead?

No, but you can trivially construct any [typed array "view"](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Typed_arrays) that you need on that buffer:

```
new Int16Array(fileReader.result)
```